# Разделение данных по типу без условных конструкций

Tags: java

Привет сообществу.

Возможно ли (и если да, то стоит ли) обойтись без условных конструкций,
если нужно задействовать различные алгоритмы для разных типов входных данных?

Например, есть таблица с данными (можно пройтись по ячейкам) и есть массив значений 
соответствующей размерности, которые в этой таблице должны быть. Каждое из значений может быть одного из нескольких типов (предположим, String или Image) и должно по-своему сверяться с ячейкой. Можно ли организовать проверку так, чтобы избежать (не перенести, а вообще не использовать) конструкций типа

```
if (expected instanceof String) {...}
```

Как я понимаю, если это возможно, то с помощью обобщений, но не могу сообразить как.

**UPD.**
Значения для проверки хранятся в переменных одного типа - Object, так как передаются через единую структуру (например, так: `Object[] expectedValues`). Поэтому не выходит положиться на проверку типов при компиляции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попахивает паттерном Стратегия. Разделите объекты по типам и назначьте для каждого типа свою стратегию.

Например, что-то наподобие такого

```
abstract class MyObject {
    Types getType();
}

interface ProcessingStrategy {
    void process(MyObject object);
}

enum Types {
    IMAGE(MY_IMAGE_STRATEGY),
    TEXT(MY_TEXT_STRATEGY),
    CUSTOM(CUSTOM_STRATEGY);

    private final ProcessingStrategy strategy;
    private Types(ProcessingStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public ProcessingStrategy getStrategy() {
         return strategy;
    }
}

//......
List<MyObject> objs = ....
for (MyObject obj : objs) 
    obj.getType().getStrategy().process(obj);
```

PS: а как вы думаете Generics использовать для этого? Я не представляю себе такое. Generics работают только на этапе компиляции + проверки в рантайме. Так что то что вы хотите будет нельзя сделать

Comment: Изначально хотелось избежать оборачивания существующих типов данных своими, но видимо, это неизбежно.
Спасибо, посмотрим, если это будет стоит того, то таки стратегию и задействую.

Comment: Ещё вы можете сделать мапу классов на стратегии. Тогда не придётся делать классы-обёртки, но зато придётся поддерживать мапу.

Answer (score 1):

простой способ:

```
interface TypeHandler
{
   public void handle ( Object object );
   public boolean canHandle(Object object);
}
class GenericHandler implements TypeHandler
{
   private final List < TypeHandler > handlers = new LinkedList < TypeHandler > ();

   public GenericHandler ()
   {
      // инициализируем список в правильном порядке
   }

   @Override
   public boolean canHandle ( final Object object )
   {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void handle ( final Object object )
   {
      for ( final TypeHandler handler : handlers )
      {
         if ( handler.canHandle ( object ) )
         {
            handler.handle ( object );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

более продвинутый:

```
interface TypeHandler
{
   public void handle ( Object object );
}
class DefaultHandler implements TypeHandler
{
   @Override
   public void handle ( final Object object )
   {
      System.out.println ( object );
   }
}
class NumberHandler implements TypeHandler
{
   @Override
   public void handle ( final Object object )
   {
      System.out.println ( "number = " + object );
   }
}
class GenericHandler implements TypeHandler
{
   private final Map < Class < ? >, TypeHandler > handlers = new HashMap < Class < ? >, TypeHandler > ();

   public GenericHandler ()
   {
      register ( Object.class, new DefaultHandler () );
      register ( String.class, new DefaultHandler () );
      register ( Number.class, new NumberHandler () );
   }

   public TypeHandler getHandler ( final Object o )
   {
      // default
      if ( null == o )
      {
         return handlers.get ( Object.class );
      }

      return getHandler ( o.getClass () );
   }

   @Override
   public void handle ( final Object object )
   {
      getHandler ( object ).handle ( object );
   }

   public void register ( final Class clazz, final TypeHandler typeHandler )
   {
      handlers.put ( clazz, typeHandler );
   }

   public void unregister ( final Class clazz )
   {
      handlers.remove ( clazz );
   }

   private TypeHandler getHandler ( final Class clazz )
   {
      final TypeHandler typeHandler = handlers.get ( clazz );

      // handler found
      if ( null != typeHandler )
      {
         return typeHandler;
      }

      // search dynamically for super class handlers
      return getHandler ( clazz.getSuperclass () );
   }
}
```

использование:

```
  final GenericHandler hander = new GenericHandler ();
  hander.handle ( "hello world" );
  hander.handle ( new Integer ( 15 ) );
  hander.handle ( new Double ( 16.5 ) );
  hander.handle ( new Date () );
  hander.handle ( new GenericHandler () );
```

вывод:

```
hello world
number = 15
number = 16.5
Thu May 19 21:06:04 EEST 2011
jmu.diplom.steganography.dcp.koh.GenericHandler@1ff9dc36
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так?

```
public boolean check( Image value){ ... }
public boolean check( String value ){ ... }
public boolean check( int value ){ ... }
....

String s = "bla";
if( check( s ) ){ ... } // вызовется public boolean check( String value ){ ... }
```

Comment: спасибо, не совсем то. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Минимальный пример сделайте, что есть вот такой-то код, как сделать без instanceof